# angular show certain html from child component inside parent component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So what I want to do is to be able to show only a certain part of the HTML from a child component inside a parent component. For example, this is how my child component would look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row chart-container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!-- childHtml is the div I want to show inside the parent component -->
            <div id="childHtml"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this is how the parent component would look like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- this div is from the child component shown above -->
        <div id="childHtml"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way to extract only that certain div? I've tried searching for something similar but haven't come across anything helpful yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's [content projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/). It seems to be an underdocumented feature but here is a simple example selecting to project all content inside `child` tags:

```
<parent>
  Some stuff you don't want
  <child>
     Stuff you want
  </child>
</parent>
```

Parent HTML:

```
<ng-content select="child">
</ng-content>
```

More complex CSS selectors are also possible as you'll see in the link.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of an actual situation where this is used? I tried following your example but it's not working as I expected

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a boolean value to the child component through @Input like showDiv.

```
<child [showDiv]="true">
</child>
```

Capture showDiv as @Input() showDiv in child component ts.
Use showDiv in child component html.

```
<div *ngIf="showDiv" id="childHtml"></div>
```

Comment: could you provide a source or a more detailed explanation?

Comment: It's simple. look into how to use @input in angular to pass between different components. For example : https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/passing-data-angular-2-components-input